# Symfony 4 Custom Validator Constraint is not loading

Tags: php, symfony, validation, constraints

I'm trying to create a custom Validator in my Symfony 4.4 project described in https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

I have added the next files:

> src/Validator/Constraints/PhoneNumber.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class PhoneNumber extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'The string contains an illegal character: it can only contain letters or numbers.';
}
```

> src/Validator/Constraints/PhoneNumberValidator.php

```
namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedValueException;

class PhoneNumberValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        dd('er wordt gevalideerd!');

        if (!$constraint instanceof PhoneNumber) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, PhoneNumber::class);
        }

        // custom constraints should ignore null and empty values to allow
        // other constraints (NotBlank, NotNull, etc.) take care of that
        if (null === $value || '' === $value) {
            return;
        }

        if (!is_string($value)) {
            // throw this exception if your validator cannot handle the passed type so that it can be marked as invalid
            throw new UnexpectedValueException($value, 'string');

            // separate multiple types using pipes
            // throw new UnexpectedValueException($value, 'string|int');
        }

        if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $value, $matches)) {
            // the argument must be a string or an object implementing __toString()
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('{{ string }}', $value)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

> config/validator/validation.yaml

```
App\Entity\AcmeEntity:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - App\Validator\Constraints\ContainsAlphanumeric: ~
```

After i have tried the above the validator doesn't respond...
So next thing i have tried is to add the validator constraint to my Entity Contact.

> src/Entity/Contact.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use App\Validator\Constraints as CustomAssert ;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ContactRepository")
 */
class Contact
{

    .....


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @CustomAssert\PhoneNumber
     */
    private $phoneNumber;
```

This is also not working.

Someone who see what i am doing wrong or have a suggestion for what i can try?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to ask the obvious thing: have you checked whether the validator is triggered after all? If you use an existing constraint and post invalid data, does the request fail?

Comment: My belief is he has (hence `dd('er wordt gevalideerd!');`). Can you give us an example of the invalid value you're testing this with?

Comment: A couple of sidenotes: remove `->setParameter('{{ string }}', $value)` from your builder call, you don't have a parameter in your message. Also, you don't need `$matches` in your `preg_match`call, since you're not using them in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible that the contraint you are looking for is set from a related entity?
if so, then try to pass the validation from the first to the second entity.

This can be done by:

```
@Assert\Valid()
```

dont forget to use it:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

```html
class Contact
{

    .....


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @CustomAssert\PhoneNumber
     */
    private $phoneNumber;
    
    
    
class Person
{

    .....


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Contact")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $contact;
```

Comment: Thank you! You made my day... after i added @Assert\Valid() to my Parent Entity the custom validation was called. After that i had a specific error message. I have changed in my PhoneNumberValidator file the extend to ConstraintValidator instead of Constraint.

Comment: This! I struggled so hard to figured this one out, glad I stumbled upon this post!

Answer (score 2):

you can try to implement the 
`validateBy` method in your `PhoneNumber` class.
In normal cases you don't need to do that because the default behavior is to look for 
the same Constraint name suffixed by `Validator` (which will be `PhoneNumberValidator`).

An other reason for that is could be the call to `validate` method of the `ValidatorInterface`. Maybe you're passing some validations groups (if you can share that part with us here) and in that case you i'll need to specify that in the annotation `@CustomAssert\PhoneNumber(groups={"some_group"})`.